# AWS Service quota per user?

Tags: amazon-web-services

There are several "accounts" in an AWS OU in my organization to isolate service utilization, billing, etc. But, these accounts don't necessarily provide any restrictions w.r.t the number of resources a user ( say in an Active Directory environment ) can use.
I am just wondering if there are any provisions in place for AWS to be able to restrict a specific user to not consume more than the allotted 'quota'?

I am a novice in the AWS area, please excuse me if there is any ambiguity in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can think of.

If you really want to do this (restrict number of resources per user), you can create one account per user and restrict their rights so that they cannot request quota increase. This may not be a practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not associate resources with users.

When a user makes a request to create a resource (eg an Amazon EC2 instance), IAM will confirm that they are entitled to create the resource. If so, then the resource is created in the AWS Account associated with that user. There is **no connection made between that resource and the user** (aside from an entry in CloudTrail that records the creation request).

Comment: Thanks, John. I kinda sensed that might be the answer but was hopeful that there could be a such option.